# Why is ServerContext always null?

Tags: user-profile-service

I have a web part, hosted within a SharePoint 2007 site that has Forms Authentication enabled. During the registration process, I allow users to upload a profile image which gets stored within ASP Membership provider, but I need to add the image to the MOSS User profile as well.

After some research, I figured that this can be achieved through the MOSS UserProfile class but it can only be accessed through a server context.

I've added the requirements including Microsoft.Office.Server.dll to my application and have access to ServerContext, but regardless of how I try to access the context, it always comes back un-instantiated:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost:1999")
{
     ServerContext sc = ServerContext.GetContext(site);
}
```

I'm assuming this is because I'm running the web site through a local host instance and not a named instance?

Is there any other particular reason why the context would be null?

Edit: turns out that SSP was the issue, thanks Andreas.

Comment: Hi Andreas, no SSP is not enabled as I'm testing this on a localized instance of SharePoint. Figured I don't need to go through the hassle. is SSP an absolute MUST? why?

Comment: Can you accept @Andreas' answer? I updated it to be an answer instead of a comment. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSP (Shared Service Provider) must installed and configured properly. You can [create a new SSP through Central Administration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262649%28office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: I rephrased your answer here and added a link. Feel free to edit as you see fit.